# array not saving calculations?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simply cart array, that I want to update if the user selects the same product again.  If they already have 5 pencils in their cart, and they add to cart 4 more pencils, I want them to have 9 pencils in their cart, not two entries for pencils of 5 and 4.

The code I have this:

```
$sub = array("id" => $_POST['pID'], "name" => $_POST['pName'], "price" => $_POST['pPrice'], "quantity" => (int) $_POST['pQuant']);
$updated = false;
foreach($cart as $c)
{
    if($c['id']==$_POST['pID']) {
        var_dump($c); 
        echo "<br>";

        $c['quantity'] += (int) $_POST['pQuant'];
        var_dump($c); 
        echo "<br>";
        var_dump($cart); 
        echo "<br>";
        $updated = true;
    }

}

if(!$updated) {$cart[] = $sub;}
```

For some stupid reason, (Im sure it's a really obvious thing i'm missing here), the first `var_dump` of $c is fine.  That's the original values.  Then the second `var_dump`, has the number added onto it.  However on the third `var_dump`, of `$cart`, The value hasn't changed?

I don't get why.

Comment: is $c a copy of an element of cart, or is it a reference to the original? If it's a copy, then changing it doesn't change the cart...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the `foreach` the variable `$c` is only a copy of the basket item, so you update the copy, but not the original item within `$cart`. This can be circumvented by using a reference for `$c` instead:

```
foreach($cart as &$c)
```

Notice the `&` in front of `$c`.

Comment: I think this is the most compact solution - it gets my +1

Comment: Hmm, I can't believe I have never run into this problem before to learn that! How strange, Oh well, that's pretty usefull I suppose.  Do you know what the & operator is called in PHP? What is the name what i'm doing there?

Comment: I guess it's just called reference operator. The PHP manual explains this in great detail here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php - However the `foreach` example is a special case, the operator is usually used to create references manually, like `$a=&$b`.

Comment: @WolfgangStengel Thank you very much, I am embarressed that I didn't know foreach did that all this time! It's funny though because I guess then I've always used foreach to read and never write.  Which, again is strange.  Anyway thank you; I am most grateful.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` creates a copy of the original array. To work with the original array, use this:

```
foreach(array_keys($cart) as $k) {
    $c = &$cart[$k];
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this over WolfgangStengel's method? I am wondering, because you have such a high reputation.

Comment: Not really, they both do the same thing. I guess his is slightly more efficient, although I think mine's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that foreach uses not references. It uses values. If you want to change `$cart` you have two ways:

```
foreach($cart as $key => $c) {
    $cart[$key]['quantity'] = += (int) $_POST['pQuant'];
}
```

The alternative:

```
foreach($cart as &$c) {// use a reference
[...]    
}
```